# Flot Graphs: Dual axis line chart, stacking ONE axis

Tags: javascript, html, charts, flot

I am hoping someone out there can tell me if what I am trying to do is even possible with the FLOT Javascript library.  I am trying to show a chart (below) with dual axis and three data sets.  One data set is on the left axis and two data sets on the right axis.  What I really want to be able to do is stack the two data sets on the right axis since they should show cumulatively.  Thus far I have been unable to get this chart to respond to the stack: true setting at all.

If anyone could help me out with it I would GREATLY appreciate it.  My code and a snapshot of the chart currently.  I am trying to stack the blue and green areas which correspond to the right axis (y2).

[image: I am trying to stack the blue and green areas which correspond to the right axis (y2)]

```
$(function () {
var previousPoint;

var completes = [[1346954400000, 5], [1346997600000, 5], [1347040800000, 7], [1347084000000, 9], [1347127200000, 12], [1347170400000, 15], [1347213600000, 16], [1347256800000, 20], [1347300000000, 20], [1347343200000, 20], [1347386400000, 25]];
var holds = [[1346954400000, 2], [1346997600000, 2], [1347040800000, 6], [1347084000000, 12], [1347127200000, 12], [1347170400000, 15], [1347213600000, 24], [1347256800000, 24], [1347300000000, 24], [1347343200000, 24], [1347386400000, 25]];
var screeners = [[1346954400000, 10298], [1346997600000, 7624], [1347040800000, 5499], [1347084000000, 2100], [1347127200000, 8075], [1347170400000, 4298], [1347213600000, 1134], [1347256800000, 507], [1347300000000, 0], [1347343200000, 800], [1347386400000, 120]];




var ds = new Array();

ds.push({
    data:completes,
    label: "Complete",
    yaxis: 2,
    lines: {
        show: true, 
        fill: true, 
        order: 2,
    }
});
ds.push({
    data:screeners,
    label: "Pre-Screened",
    yaxis: 1,
    lines: {
        show: true, 
        fill: true, 
        order: 1,
    }
});
ds.push({
    data:holds,
    label: "Holds",
    yaxis: 2,
    lines: {
        show: true, 
        fill: true, 
        order: 3,
    }
});

//tooltip function
function showTooltip(x, y, contents, areAbsoluteXY) {
    var rootElt = 'body';

    $('<div id="tooltip2" class="tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css( {
        position: 'absolute',
        display: 'none',
        top: y - 35,
        left: x - 5,
        border: '1px solid #000',
        padding: '1px 5px',
        'z-index': '9999',
        'background-color': '#202020',
        'color': '#fff',
        'font-size': '11px',
        opacity: 0.8
    }).prependTo(rootElt).show();
}

//Display graph
$.plot($("#placeholder1"), ds, {
    grid:{
        hoverable:true
    },
    xaxes: [ { mode: 'time', twelveHourClock: true, timeformat: "%m/%d %H:%M" } ],
    yaxes: [ {  min: 0,
                tickFormatter: function numberWithCommas(x) 
                {
                    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                },
             } 
            ],
    y2axis: [ ],
    legend: { show: true }
});
```

});

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is very straightforward.  The stacking plugin isn't well documented, but in the [source code](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/jquery.flot.stack.js), you can see there are two ways to specify that you want stacking turned on.

> Two or more series are stacked when their "stack" attribute is set to
>   the same key (which can be any number or string or just "true"). To
>   specify the default stack, you can set
>
> series: {
>       stack: null or true or key (number/string)   }
>
> or specify it for a specific series
>
> $.plot($("#placeholder"), [{ data: [ ... ], stack: true }])

In this case, we want to specify it within the two series objects that we want stacked, which would look like this:

```
ds.push({
    data:completes,
    label: "Complete",
    yaxis: 2,
    stack: true,  //added
    lines: {
        show: true, 
        fill: true, 
        order: 2,
    }
});
ds.push({
    data:screeners,
    label: "Pre-Screened",
    yaxis: 1,
    lines: {
        show: true, 
        fill: true, 
        order: 1,
    }
});
ds.push({
    data:holds,
    label: "Holds",
    yaxis: 2,
    stack: true,  //added
    lines: {
        show: true, 
        fill: true, 
        order: 3,
    }
});
```

Add those two `stack:true` bits and include the stack plugin into your javascript sources and that will do it.  See it in action here:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/zNXBd/

Comment: 100% awesome.  It amazes me sometimes how it's the simple things that always get us.  I had tried that (and various other means) trying to get this to work.  In the end I wasn't loading my stack library.  (I know, I know)  However, just having someone prove it CAN be done and confirming how to do it was the key.  JSFiddle is the coolest thing I've seen in a while BTW, my thanks again!